# Why is the presence of middleware preventing execution of an endpoint?

Tags: asp.net

I am a beginner at ASP.Net.  Here is my startup.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using CAPSWebServer.CapsDataModels;

namespace CAPSWebServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            Configuration = config;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CapsDataContext>(opts =>
            {
                opts.UseNpgsql(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:CAPSConnection"]);
                opts.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseMiddleware<TestMiddleware>();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my TestMiddleware class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CAPSWebServer.CapsDataModels;

namespace CAPSWebServer
{
    public class TestMiddleware
    {
        private RequestDelegate nextDelegate;

        public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            nextDelegate = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, CapsDataContext dataContext)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path == "/test")
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"There are {dataContext.Charges.Count()} charges.\n");
                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"There are {dataContext.Inventories.Count()} coils.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This application is configured to listen on port 500 of my computer.  When I run localhost:5000/test, I get the expected report of how many charges and coils I have in my database.  But when I run localhost:5000 by itself, I get nothing.  I think I should be getting "Hello, world".  If I comment out out the call to UseMiddleware(), I get "Hello, world".  Why does the middleware block the endpoint?

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: thats because you need to execute the next delegate by calling nextDelegate()

Comment: Ah, yes.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I am gonna post it as answer just so that other people might benefit from internet searches

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the

```
nextDelegate();
```

So that the next middleware down the line is executed.

The reason it works when the URL contains "/test" is because you are writing directly into the response stream.